# pushing into arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript

My script (is meant to) grab text from the a page (which works fine) and then splits it by by newline (\n) and puts each splitted string into an array called "dnaSequence"; from there it loops through each element in the array and if the string contains the character ">" it assigns that string to the "var header_name", else it pushes all other lines into a new array called "dnaSubseq". The original text looks something like this:

```
>header_1
gctagctagc
cgcgagcgagc
>header_2
gcgcatgcgac
```

When I execute the code it fails to alert on anything. Here is the code:

```
function loaderMy() {

var dnaSubseq = [];
var dnaSequence = [];
var header_name = "";
var splittedLines = document.getElementById("page-wrapper").innerText;
dnaSequence = splittedLines.split('\n');

for (var i = 0; i < dnaSequence.length; i++) {
    if (dnaSequence[i].match(/>/)) {
        header_name = dnaSequence[i];
        alert(header_name);
    }
    else {
        dnaSubseq.pushValues(dnaSequence[i]);
    }
    alert(dnaSubseq);
}
}
```

Comment: `push` not `pushValues`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
dnaSubseq.pushValues(dnaSequence[i]);
```

To

```
dnaSubseq.push(dnaSequence[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't alert anything, that means you forgot to invoke the function :)

```
loaderMy();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zszyg5qx/

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
function loaderMy() {
    var dnaSubseq = [];
    var dnaSequence = [];
    var header_name = "";
    var splittedLines = document.getElementById("page-wrapper").innerText;
    dnaSequence = splittedLines.split('\n');

    for (var i = 0; i < dnaSequence.length; i++) {
        if (dnaSequence[i].match(/>/)) {
            header_name = dnaSequence[i];
            alert(header_name);
       }
       else {
               dnaSubseq.push(dnaSequence[i]);
       }
  alert(dnaSubseq);
}
}
```